# Strange behavior with CSS border-radius issue

Tags: css, border-radius

I've the follow html with CSS

```css
.image_with_loader_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 139.34426%;
  background: #dbdbdb;
}

.image_with_loader_container img {
  border-radius: 4.75%/3.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_with_loader_container">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

In this [video](https://streamable.com/acsnex) (Chrome 83) you can see that the border-radius doesn't work very well. You can check this behavior live at https://mtgprint.cardtrader.com .

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need `background: #dbdbdb;` in your `.image_with_loader_container`? Try without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding rounded corners to the image, but the container with `background: #dbdbdb;` is still a rectangle. (You can see it better if you set your radius to a large value, like 100%). Try either removing that background, or adding the same border-radius to `.image_with_loader_container`.